# Getting null current location

Tags: android, location

I am first time working with location in android studio. And the problem is that I am getting null location. I don't understand why? I have given all permissions like access_course, fine location. On my emulator it gives me dummy location (in some other continent) and on my real device it shows me 0.0,0.0 coordinates. My location class code is as follows:

```
public class LocationClass extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
boolean checkGPS = false;


boolean checkNetwork = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location loc;
double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;


private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public LocationClass(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}

private Location getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // get GPS status
        checkGPS = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get network provider status
        checkNetwork = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider is available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (checkGPS) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }
            if (checkNetwork) {


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                }

                if (loc != null) {
                    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;

}
public double getLongitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not Enabled!");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on GPS?");


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}
public void stopListener() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationClass.this);
    }
}
```

and other override methods so on.I am sending my location through broadcast so My broadcast code is :

```
            if (messageReceived.equals(location))
             {
            LocationClass locationClass;
            locationClass = new LocationClass(context);
            if (locationClass.canGetLocation()) {

                double longitude = locationClass.getLongitude();
                double latitude = locationClass.getLatitude();

                String message = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+Double.toString(latitude)+","+Double.toString(longitude);

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager. getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact, null, message , null, null);

            } else {

                locationClass.showSettingsAlert();
            }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: O! I didn't knew that...Thanks for telling and editing my question.